# Google Cloud SQL - Export API - PostgreSQL : Error 400 The requested operation is not valid for a read-replica instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-storage, export-to-csv, google-cloud-sql

I have two Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instances : one master and one read-only replica.

When I try to export the datas from the read-only replica to a given bucket using the Cloud SQL v1beta4 Export API (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export), with the following request body :

```
{
  "exportContext": {
    "kind": "sql#exportContext",
    "fileType": "CSV",
    "uri": "gs://bucket_uri",
    "databases": [
      "db_name"
    ],
    "csvExportOptions": {
      "selectQuery": "SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The requested operation is not valid for a read-replica instance.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The requested operation is not valid for a read-replica instance.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "errorReadReplicaInvalidOperation"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I use the master instance, everything works fine.

I also did the same thing but with a Cloud SQL MySQL instance, and the export API was working well on the read-only replica, that's why I'm surprised it's not working on a PostgreSQL read-only replica instance.

I don't want to plug my export on the master instance as the instance is already busy enough. Do you have encountered the same kind of issue ? Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to oficial documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#csv).

> Note: You cannot export to a CSV file from a read replica instance.
>   The export operation creates an export user and grants that user
>   select permissions on the database the user wants to export. Since
>   read replica instances run in read only mode, these operations fail.

Since this instance is a replica, any transactions to it will be considered as read-only. Basically, with the read-only constraint the permission granting will fail.The current workaround is to do the exports in MASTER instance instead of REPLICA as you mentioned.

Comment: I just discovered this information is not in the french version of the documentation but is indeed in the english version, my bad. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Please accept my answer if helpful, for greater visibility for the community.